# left join for count() column in two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I just set the query as below to make a data table count the column for different table

```
select a.user_id, count(a.account) as a_cou, b.user_id, count(b.account) as b_cou
from a_table as a 
left join b_table as b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
group by a.user_id
```

but there is a problem that, if I set the query like this,

a_cou and b_cou table are shown as the same amount,
I think b table is overwrite from a table,

how to make the right query for join the column?

Comment: `b_cou` shouldn't count the null values when there's no match. Otherwise, the counts are the same because you're counting rows, not values. Maybe you want `COUNT(DISTINCT b.account)`?

Comment: You should please provide sample data and expected result, please.

Comment: *`count(x.account)`* counts the total amount of non-NULL values. If there is no NULLs in these columns and there is no a row in `a` without matched row in `b` then both counts will produce the same value (and the same value which will be produced by `count(*)`).

Comment: We can't do more without table definitions and sample data

Answer (score 0):

Since you are LEFT-JOINING to B, the count is still relying on A existing and thus a false value.  Try changing to a SUM() based on the value null or not in the B table.  If Null, 0, otherwise 1.

Additionally, when using a GROUP BY, you have to include all non-aggregates in the group by clause.  Since you are joining on A.User = B.User, it is not needed to show the duplicate column.  You should be able to see the NULL count vs actual count from the B table.

```
select 
      a.user_id, 
      count(a.account) as a_cou, 
      sum( case when b.user_id IS NULL then 0 else 1 end ) as b_cou
   from 
      a_table as a 
         left join b_table as b
            on a.user_id = b.user_id
   group by 
      a.user_id
```